# C# - rewrite delegate calls to Action<>

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, anonymous-function

I have a need to wrap a number of functions with code that will pre-process input data for these functions ("Wrapper"). Here's the code written using delegates (the code is simplified as much as possible, while still functional and immediately compilable):

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class ClientContext
    {
        public int i = 1;
    }

    class SPRemoteEventProperties
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        public delegate void Del(ClientContext clientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties properties);

        public static void Wrapper(Del f, ClientContext clientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            ClientContext newClientContext = new ClientContext
            {
                i = clientContext.i * 2
            };

            f(newClientContext, properties);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Function1(new ClientContext(), new SPRemoteEventProperties());
            Function2(new ClientContext(), new SPRemoteEventProperties());

            Wrapper(Function1, new ClientContext(), new SPRemoteEventProperties());
            Wrapper(Function2, new ClientContext(), new SPRemoteEventProperties());

            Console.Read();
        }

        static void Function1(ClientContext clientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Function1: " + clientContext.i);
        }

        static void Function2(ClientContext clientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Function2: " + clientContext.i);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, to simplify the code I'd like to rewrite it using Action<> syntax and inline the functions' code. Here's what I tried to do, but I can't manage to write a correct and functioning program:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class ClientContext
    {
        public int i = 1;
    }

    class SPRemoteEventProperties
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        Action<ClientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties> Act;

        // error in next line =>
        public static void Wrapper(Act f, ClientContext clientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            ClientContext newClientContext = new ClientContext
            {
                i = clientContext.i * 2
            };

            f(newClientContext, properties);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Function1(new ClientContext(), new SPRemoteEventProperties());
            Function2(new ClientContext(), new SPRemoteEventProperties());

            // error in next 2 lines =>
            Wrapper((new ClientContext(), new SPRemoteEventProperties()) => Console.WriteLine("Function1: " + clientContext.i));
            Wrapper((new ClientContext(), new SPRemoteEventProperties()) => Console.WriteLine("Function2: " + clientContext.i));

            Console.Read();
        }

        static void Function1(ClientContext clientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Function1: " + clientContext.i);
        }

        static void Function2(ClientContext clientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Function2: " + clientContext.i);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me correct this code?

Comment: Try passing `Action<ClientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties> f` in the `Wrapper` params instead of `Act f`

Comment: You are replacing one delegate type with another. Previous delegate type was `Del`. New delegate type is `Action<ClientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties>`. So just replace usage of one with another (you use it in just one place), and delete `Del` type, as it's no longer needed.

Comment: `Action<ClientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties> Act;` is not a type definition. But you do try to use it so.

Comment: Action<ClientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties> f ... as the Wrapper's first argument resolved the first error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure i fully understand what you are trying to do, am i close?

```
public static void Wrapper(ClientContext clientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties properties, Action<ClientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties> action)
{
    action(newClientContext, properties);
}

...
Wrapper( new ClientContext(), new SPRemoteEventProperties(),(context, properties) => Console.WriteLine("Function1: " + context.i));
```

Comment: Yes, this resolves the inline syntax part. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `Action` is different than a `delegate`:

While the `delegate` syntax define a type declaration that you can use to define a variable, the `Action` syntax is already the type, and you can use it to create your variable.
*I'm not sure i'm clear, but, following is the correct syntax to use:*

```
 public static void Wrapper(Action<ClientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties> f, ClientCo ...
```

Answer (score 1):

An `Action` has the diamond notation (`<>`) after it, which is a sign that it is a generic type. Unlike `delegate`, it contains everything the compiler needs to make it type safe. This differs from `delegate` which is not really typed until you define a specific delegate, which tells the compiler the types of all the parameters. With the `Action` you just need to put the types into the diamond and voila, it is a complete type now.

Since the parameter name is always preceded by its type, your prototype should read like this:

```
public static void Wrapper(Action<ClientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties> f, ClientContext clientContext, SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
{
```

That is everything the compiler needs to know about what is going to be contained in that argument, type-wise.